# Origem e significado da expressão "que nem ginjas"

Tags: significado, português-europeu, expressões, origem

No mercado perguntei

> Boas NOME, estas maçãs são boas?

A resposta foi

> Sim, vendem-se **que nem ginjas**!

O contexto aponta para que seja vender bem, mas não sou grande fã de ginjas...

Comment: Já procurou em algum lugar?

Comment: Talvez isto dê ajuda: https://dicionario.priberam.org/ginja.

Comment: @Lambie sim, no Priberam, mas não diz de onde vem essa expressão

Comment: Por aqui no mercado de Almada, ginjas vendem-se muito rápido e mais caras do que a cereja doce no pouco tempo que estão disponíveis (início de Junho). Mas pode ser por a produção ser mais baixa.

Comment: A expressão foi popularizada pelo **licor de ginja**, também conhecido por [ginjinha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginjinha)... Frequentmente bebo uma ginjinha se estiver a passear pelos sítios onde é popular o licor, como o largo de São Domingos na baixa de Lisboa, Óbidos ou Alcobaça. Como diz o @Artefacto a ginja enquanto fruto parece ser da época pois eu nunca a vi à venda, enquanto o licor se encontra o ano inteiro. Tentei pesquisar a origem do licor propriamente dito e parece ser pelo menos do ínicio de 1800...

Comment: Outra fonte confirmando o significado de "muito bom/bem", "vir muito a propósito": https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-significado-da-expressao-calharcair-que-nem-ginjas/28271